# geofencing no longer relaunch app from terminated state in ios7?

Tags: ios7, background, ibeacon, geofencing, location-based

I'm developing an app which uses ibeacon to determine if the user entered a specific region.
Now I'm using the CoreLocation framework to implement this geofencing-based feature.
I've read the document below.
https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManager_Class/CLLocationManager/CLLocationManager.html
in which the Apple is saying that: 
"In iOS, the regions you register with the location manager persist between launches of your application. If a region crossing occurs while your iOS app is not running, the system automatically wakes it up (or relaunches it) in the background so that it can process the event. When relaunched, all of the regions you configured previously are made available in the monitoredRegions property of any location manager objects you create. "

I discovered that it's true just before the ios 7.
From ios 7, An app will be waken-up from background but it will actually no longer could be re-launched from terminated-state (slided out from the task manager which displayed by double-clicking the home button).
If it's due to the Apple's policies, why does Apple not update the above official document?
So I'm thinking of an ios7's bug because the Reminder App (a built-in app) is also not relaunched in ios7 even though it's relaunched in ios6.
Is this issue due to Apple's policies? or an ios7's bugs?
It takes me more than 2 days to google for a solution.
Any ideas for this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation is simply out of date.  This is intended behavior in iOS7.  Apple produced a video explicitly discussing this change. The idea is that if the user explicitly terminates the app, the user does not want it running.  [See this thread.](https://devforums.apple.com/message/886796#886796)

Is this such a big deal?  How often will users really do this?  Remember, if users are annoyed by you app, they can always uninstall it, too.  This was true in iOS6.

Comment: Thank you for the link.
Perhaps, I should agree with you.

Answer (score 0):

iOS 7.1 reversed this policy. That is even if the user kills your app the iOS still launches your app upon crossing the region.

Comment: I'm not seeing this on iOS 7.1.2 on an iPhone 4S - if I kill the app in the task switcher the app isn't relaunched, but if the OS kills the app due to memory pressure I do see the app relaunched when entering a region.